# A string ref, "grid", has been found within a strict mode tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing given warning in console:

> Warning: A string ref, "grid", has been found within a
>   strict mode tree. String refs are a source of potential bugs and
>   should be avoided. We recommend using useRef() or createRef() instead.

Here's my line of codes:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="notes-app"> 
        <h2 className="app-header">NotesApp</h2> 
        <NoteSearch onSearch={text => this.handleSearch(text)} />
        <NoteEditor onNoteAdd={this.handleNoteAdd} />
        <NotesGrid
          notes={this.state.filteredNotes}
          onNoteDelete={this.handleNoteDelete}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[image: string ref warning]

The snippet of the code editor shows the lines where the warning is pointed 
[image: Code]

The NotesGrid component is as follows:

```js
import Masonry from "masonry-layout";

import React from 'react';
import Note from "./Note";
export default class NotesGrid extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      var grid = this.refs.grid;
      this.msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
        itemSelector: ".note",
        columnWidth: 200,
        gutter: 10,
        isFitWidth: true
      });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.notes.length !== prevProps.notes.length) {
        this.msnry.reloadItems();
        this.msnry.layout();
      }
    }

    render() {
      var onNoteDelete = this.props.onNoteDelete;

      return (
        <div className="notes-grid" ref="grid"> //here I Have used the ref
          {this.props.notes.map(function(note) {
            return (
              <Note
                key={note.id}
                onDelete={onNoteDelete.bind(null, note)}
                color={note.color}
              >
                {note.text}
              </Note>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

What's the best alternative to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the NotesGrid as below

```
import Masonry from "masonry-layout";
import React from 'react';

import Note from "./Note";

export default class NotesGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.gridRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.msnry = new Masonry(this.gridRef.current, {
      itemSelector: ".note",
      columnWidth: 200,
      gutter: 10,
      isFitWidth: true
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.notes.length !== prevProps.notes.length) {
      this.msnry.reloadItems();
      this.msnry.layout();
    }
  }

  render() {
    var onNoteDelete = this.props.onNoteDelete;

    return (
      <div className="notes-grid" ref={this.gridRef}>
        {this.props.notes.map((note) => (
          <Note
            key={note.id}
            onDelete={onNoteDelete.bind(null, note)}
            color={note.color}
          >
            {note.text}
          </Note>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the component **NotesGrid**. Check whether the component has usage of 'ref' or not.
If ref is using in that component. create the **ref** using React.createRef() (if its a class component) or using useRef(if its a functional component)

Comment: Can you brief me more on how I can do it in the NotesGrid component? I have updated the NotesGrid Component in the question.

Comment: sure. Will post the NotesGrid component below.

Comment: yeah, I was getting the error because I had declared the ref, and done stuff with it, but had not yet actually used the ref like `ref={myRef}`. Once I used it, error gone.