# A string ref, "canvas", has been found within a strict mode tree

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to use an npm package which is a simple matrix effect https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-matrix-effect but due to some bugs I just decided to copy and fixed it on my own and also modify it to my needs. I fixed few bugs there however one warning I can't figure out how to fix... I've never use canvas or refs before so it is a bit new to me

Here is the complete code

```
import React, {
   Component
} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Matrix extends Component {
   static propTypes = {
      width: PropTypes.number,
      height: PropTypes.number,
      fullscreen: PropTypes.bool,
      colSize: PropTypes.number,
      fontSize: PropTypes.number,
      interval: PropTypes.number,
      color: PropTypes.string,
      frequency: PropTypes.number,
      speed: PropTypes.number,
      style: PropTypes.object,
      zIndex: PropTypes.number
   };

   static defaultProps = {
      width: 640,
      height: 480,
      fullscreen: false,
      colSize: 11,
      fontSize: 13.5,
      interval: 30,
      color: '#00cc33',
      frequency: 0.005,
      speed: 1.6
   };

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         canvas: null
      };

      this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
      this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ canvas: this.refs.canvas }, () => {
         let columns = [];
         let context = this.state.canvas.getContext('2d');
         let size = this.props.colSize;
         let source = '0 0 1 1';
         let width = this.props.fullscreen ? window.innerWidth : this.props.width;
         let height = this.props.fullscreen ? window.innerHeight : this.props.height;
         let canvas = this.state.canvas;
         canvas.width = width;
         canvas.height = height;

         let numberOfColumns = Math.floor(width / size * 3 );

         this.setState({canvas, columns, context, size, source, numberOfColumns}, () => {

            for (let i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
               columns.push(0)
            }

            this.draw();
            let interval = setInterval(this.draw, 50 / this.props.speed);
            this.setState({interval});

            if (this.props.fullscreen)
               window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions);
         });
      });
   }

   draw() {
      let context = this.state.context;
      let columns = this.state.columns;
      let numberOfColumns = this.state.numberOfColumns;

      context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)';
      context.fillRect(0, 0, this.state.canvas.width, this.state.canvas.height);
      context.fillStyle = this.props.color;
      context.font = '700 ' + this.props.fontSize + 'px Consolas,monaco,monospace';

      for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
         let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.source.length);
         let character = this.state.source[index];
         let positionX = columnIndex * this.state.size;
         let positionY = columns[columnIndex] * this.state.size;

         context.fillText(character, positionX, positionY);
         if (positionY >= this.state.canvas.height && Math.random() > 1 - this.props.frequency) {
            columns[columnIndex] = 0;
         }
         columns[columnIndex]++;
      }

      this.setState({ context, columns })
   };

   updateDimensions() {
      let canvas = this.state.canvas;
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   }

   render() {
      let style = this.props.style ? this.props.style : {};
      return (
         <div style={{...style, background: '#000000', width: this.props.fullscreen ? '100vw' : this.props.width + 'px', height:  this.props.fullscreen ? '100vh' : this.props.height + 'px', overflow: 'hidden', zIndex: this.props.zIndex}}>
            <canvas ref='canvas'/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Matrix;
```

The warning is in `componentDidMount`

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ canvas: this.refs.canvas }, () => {  //<= here
         let columns = [];
```

Full warning message

> index.js:1 Warning: A string ref, "canvas", has been found within a
> strict mode tree. String refs are a source of potential bugs and
> should be avoided. We recommend using useRef() or createRef() instead

Comment: Did you read `createRef()` documentation?

Comment: Hi @DennisVash Actually I did... And I failed to implement it here.. I must have perhaps missed something but I spend like an hour with it already

Comment: Just google the error message!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012157/a-string-ref-grid-has-been-found-within-a-strict-mode-tree

Comment: @MihályiZoltán I've also been there but failed to implement it into this case

Comment: @delmin what was the problem with that solution?

Comment: @MihályiZoltán I don't think there is any problem with that solution. I just wasn't able to implement it into this case

Comment: I mean why whasn't you able to implement it? It should be the same: create a field canvasRef=createRef(), and use like this: `<canvas ref={this.canvasRef}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String refs like this: `<canvas ref='canvas'/>` store references inside `this.refs`, so this.refs.canvas can be used to reference the canvas element.
The recommended way to use refs is the following:

- create ref objects manually (in constructor): `this.canvasRef = createRef()`;
- in react nodes, use this object: `<canvas ref={this.canvasRef}/>`
- use `this.canvasRef.current` instead of this.refs.refname:

Comment: doing that I get an error on `this.state.canvas.getContext('2d')`  saying `TypeError: this.state.canvas.getContext is not a function` in `componentDidMount` Do you think you can simply copy and paste my whole code which is fully reproducible and paste it fixed to your answer?

Comment: I edited my answer: you should use `this.canvasRef.current` (not `this.canvasRef`)

Comment: oh god thank you... so there was the problem... I honestly thought I will never going to fix it

Comment: I suggest you try TypeScript, usually you can find the problem without even running the code

Comment: Yes I actually thought about it. I will have to look at it. Thanks anyway